# Test convergence of series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, ratio

Test convergence of series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^ \infty n!z^n$$

What I have done using ratio test:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert \frac{(n+1!)(z^{n+1})}{n!z^n}\rvert$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert (n+1)(z)\rvert$

And here I am kinda stuck. Do I plug in $\infty$ for n and get $\infty$ as the answer?

If $L=\infty$ then it diverges since $L>1$?

Comment: The limit depends on $|z|$.  If $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)|z|>1$ the series diverges.  Do you get $\infty$ for *every* value of $z$?

Comment: From what I can tell z is $\infty$ at every value except 0 since its $\infty$ Z and any negative value of Z becomes positive..

Comment: So it diverges for all points except z=0?

Comment: Very good, that's the answer.  It converges when $z=0$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a ton. One more question though let's say its z/(n+1). It converges right? since (1/n+1) is 0 and 0*z =0.

Comment: Yes, that's right too.